# Windows Make - No rule to make target 'echo'

Tags: powershell, makefile, echo

I'm begginer with Make and i'm stuck with the most simple makefile, I think.

I wrote the following makefile :

```
hello:
    echo "hello world"
```

And when I do in Windows Powershell :

```
PS C:\Users\Thibault\Documents\repo\myfolder> echo "hello world"
hello world
PS C:\Users\Thibault\Documents\repo\myfolder> make
make: *** No rule to make target 'echo', needed by 'hello'.  Stop.
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You must not have a newline at the end of the `hello:` target line.  What version of GNU make are you using?

Comment: I'm not using GNU, I'm on Windows Powershell. I've installed make with Chocolatey following this response (https://stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/questions/32127524/how-to-install-and-use-make-in-windows/32127632?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=fr&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=ajax,sc,elem#32127632)

Comment: That's still the GNU project's version of `make`. What is its version number?

Comment: Again, the error message suggests that you forgot to put a newline (and probably also a tab) after `hello:`. Make is very picky about these things; newlines and tabs have to be in the right places.

Comment: Run `make --version` and tell us what the output is.  However if you're using chocolately you're probably fine.  Some _very old_ versions of GNU make didn't handle Windows CRLF newlines properly, but that was versions older than 3.78.

Comment: GNU Make 4.3
Built for Windows32
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Comment: @MadScientist It works, you were right, my file format was incorrect. It was in Mac format by default (don't know why) and I had to change it to Unix in Notepad++ :)

Comment: `format-hex makefile` would show the line endings.  0D 0A is \r\n